# SQL select specific rows from subquery and insert into row_to_json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by, jsonb

I have a view for which I have created several subqueries, I'm trying to return one of the subqueries as json using -

```
row_to_json(err.*) as overall_totals
```

The subquery -

```
left join 
     (      
    SELECT q.id, SUM(q.total) AS total,
       jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('count', q.total, 'type', q.name)) AS totals
        FROM (
        SELECT r.id AS id, e.name, COUNT(de.value_id) AS total
          FROM table_c de
          JOIN tests.error e
            ON e.id = de.value_id
          JOIN table_a p 
            ON de.process_id = p.id 
          Join table_b r on p.root = r.id
         GROUP BY e.name, r.id  ) q
         GROUP BY q.id
 ) err on err.id = rs.id
```

This works fine and returns as json, however, I only want to return total and totals of the "err" sub-query and not q.id. I need the q.id in the sub-query so that I can join the query onto the rest of the view but I don't want it to be stored in overall_totals. How can I get around this? Is it possible to select certain values into row_to_json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with returning `jsonb` instead of `json`, then you can use the `-` operator:

```
to_jsonb(err.*) - 'id' as overall_totals
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more subquery, something like this

```
SELECT row_to_json(err2.*) as overall_totals
FROM
(
    SELECT err.total, err.totals
    FROM XXX_TABLE RS
    left join 
    (      
        SELECT q.id, SUM(q.total) AS total, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('count', q.total, 'type', q.name)) AS totals
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT r.id AS id, e.name, COUNT(de.value_id) AS total
            FROM table_c de
            JOIN tests.error e
            ON e.id = de.value_id
            JOIN table_a p 
            ON de.process_id = p.id 
            Join table_b r on p.root = r.id
            GROUP BY e.name, r.id  
        ) q
        GROUP BY q.id
    ) err on err.id = rs.id
) err2
```